# How make number value min/max change by select value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two value select and number

```
<select id="select-1" name="select-1" >
<option value="product-1">Product 1</option>
<option value="product-2">Product 2</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="number-1"  id="field-number-1" pattern="^\-?\d*([\.\,]\d+)?" inputmode="numeric" min="100" max="500" />
```

Using jQuery trying make min/max value update by select different product, but it not make number value update

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#select-1').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value == 'product-1') {    
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('min', '100');
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('max', '200');              
          } else if(this.value == 'product-2') {
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('min', '300');
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('max', '500');              
          } else {    
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('min', '100');
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('max', '500');
          
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `#select-1` seems like it should be `#select-1-field` and `#forminator-field-number-1` should be `#field-number-1`. Otherwise, those IDs do not exist in your snippet.

Comment: What are you referring to with "#forminator-field-number-1"?  That doesn't appear in your HTML.

Comment: change it but not solve problem

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should work fine but, since your form loads with `product-1` selected by default, you want to be sure to trigger the change event on DOM ready with `.change()`. That way the default selection and the `max` and `min` values will be consistent.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#select-1').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value == 'product-1') {    
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('min', '100');
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('max', '200');              
          } else if(this.value == 'product-2') {
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('min', '300');
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('max', '500');              
          } else {    
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('min', '100');
            jQuery('#field-number-1').attr('max', '500');
          }
          //Report if current value is valid
          jQuery('#field-number-1')[0].reportValidity();
          //delete this .... just for testing
          console.log( jQuery('#field-number-1')[0] );
        })
        .change();
        
        jQuery('#field-number-1').on('input', function(e) {
            console.log( this.checkValidity() );
            if( !this.checkValidity() ) {
                this.setCustomValidity(`Provide a number between ${$(this).attr('min')} and ${$(this).attr('max')}`);
                this.reportValidity();
            } else {
                this.setCustomValidity('');
                this.reportValidity();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1" name="select-1" >
<option value="product-1">Product 1</option>
<option value="product-2">Product 2</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="number-1"  id="field-number-1" pattern="^\-?\d*([\.\,]\d+)?" inputmode="numeric" min="100" max="500" />
```

Comment: min="100" max="200" is set, but why i can type less then 100 or more then 200, how fix this

Comment: That's a good question to ask but it's a different problem from what you've described in your question.

Comment: Can you help fix it , for ex. min value is 100 , if I put 50 it must change value to 100

Comment: to make integrate with this http://jsfiddle.net/Ddk67/75/

Comment: @jeff78592251 that is how this type of client-side validation works. The behavior is not as a result of changing `min` and `max` attributes. This is default behavior. To prevent input that's not valid from being entered you would have to create a custom validation solution based on listening to all possible events. ..... The modification in my answer simply warns (does not prevent) you as you type but if you paste the input or use the arrows to change it, you will not be warned.

Comment: thanks for help. can intagrate also this  http://jsfiddle.net/Ddk67/75/   (this prevents)

Comment: I see nothing different, nothing of note. Would you care to put it in words?

Comment: for ex. IF I have select product 1 and put number 100 and then change select to product 2 in value still showing 100. can we do when change select then resat value